# How to calculate business hours between two dates when business hours vary depending on the day in R?

Tags: r, date, datetime

I'm trying to calculate business hours between two dates. Business hours vary depending on the day.

Weekdays have 15 business hours (`8:00-23:00`), saturdays and sundays have 12 business hours (`9:00-21:00`).

For example: start date `07/24/2020 22:20` (friday) and end date `07/25/2020 21:20` (saturday), since I'm only interested in the business hours the result should be `12.67`hours.

Here an example of the dataframe and desired output:

```
start_date            end_date            business_hours
07/24/2020 22:20     07/25/2020 21:20        12.67
07/14/2020 21:00     07/16/2020 09:30        18.50
07/18/2020 08:26     07/19/2020 10:00        13.00
07/10/2020 08:00     07/13/2020 11:00        42.00
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract Business Hours between two different times values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34068109/how-to-extract-business-hours-between-two-different-times-values)

Comment: @GordonShumway It doesn't answer my question because I have business hours that vary depending on the day. I think that makes it more difficult to get the result I need.

Comment: @Ben no problem! thank you so much!

Comment: @ValeriaSalazar See edited answer using `mapply` for the data frame example.

Comment: @Ben thanks a lot! this is what I needed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is something you can try with `lubridate`. I edited another function I had I thought might be helpful.

First create a sequence of dates between the two dates of interest. Then create intervals based on business hours, checking each date if on the weekend or not.

Then, "clamp" the start and end times to the allowed business hours time intervals using `pmin` and `pmax`.

You can use `time_length` to get the time measurement of the intervals; summing them up will give you total time elapsed.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

calc_bus_hours <- function(start, end) {
  my_dates <- seq.Date(as.Date(start), as.Date(end), by = "day")
  
  my_intervals <- if_else(weekdays(my_dates) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday"),
    interval(ymd_hm(paste(my_dates, "09:00"), tz = "UTC"), ymd_hm(paste(my_dates, "21:00"), tz = "UTC")),
    interval(ymd_hm(paste(my_dates, "08:00"), tz = "UTC"), ymd_hm(paste(my_dates, "23:00"), tz = "UTC")))

  int_start(my_intervals[1]) <- pmax(pmin(start, int_end(my_intervals[1])), int_start(my_intervals[1]))
  int_end(my_intervals[length(my_intervals)]) <- pmax(pmin(end, int_end(my_intervals[length(my_intervals)])), int_start(my_intervals[length(my_intervals)]))
  
  sum(time_length(my_intervals, "hour"))
}

calc_bus_hours(as.POSIXct("07/24/2020 22:20", format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz = "UTC"), as.POSIXct("07/25/2020 21:20", format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz = "UTC"))
[1] 12.66667
```

**Edit**: For Spanish language, use `c("sábado", "domingo")` instead of `c("Saturday", "Sunday")`

For the data frame example, you can use `mapply` to call the function using the two selected columns as arguments. Try:

```
df$business_hours <- mapply(calc_bus_hours, df$start_date, df$end_date)

                start                 end business_hours
1 2020-07-24 22:20:00 2020-07-25 21:20:00       12.66667
2 2020-07-14 21:00:00 2020-07-16 09:30:00       18.50000
3 2020-07-18 08:26:00 2020-07-19 10:00:00       13.00000
4 2020-07-10 08:00:00 2020-07-13 11:00:00       42.00000
```

Comment: I'm getting as a result 14 hours, not 13. Why would that be? The result should be 12,67 hours

Comment: 09:00-21:20 on Sat. 7/25 which is 12 hrs and 20 minutes, but those 20 minutes are out of the working hours since working hours on saturday are 9:00-21:00, so I would count only 12 hours, Total 12,67 hours.

Comment: For some reason I'm getting 14 as a result, any idea why? `calc_bus_hours(as.POSIXct("07/24/2020 22:20", format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz = "UTC"), as.POSIXct("07/25/2020 21:20", format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz = "UTC"))
[1] 14`

Comment: This is the result `[1] 2020-07-24 22:20:00 UTC--2020-07-24 23:00:00 UTC 2020-07-25 08:00:00 UTC--2020-07-25 21:20:00 UTC
[1] 14`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218780/discussion-between-ben-and-valeria-salazar).